# Pre-populating Django form based on web request

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to pre-populate a Django form based on a users web request. For example, when they click on a hyperlink - http://myapp:8000//23, it returns a pre-populated django form with all the data related to the id, 23. Any hints or ideas on how to do this, step by step would be excellent. Thanks in advance.

Manny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is in the Django documentation, exactly this [Django Modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/).

First you need to define an url to obtain the object:

```python
url(r'^client/(?P<foo>\w{4})$', views.view_function, name='element'),
```

And the view function should be like this:

```python
def view_function(request, foo):
 obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=foo) # Django shortcut
 form = NameForm(instance=obj)

 return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'form': form})
```

With this you will pre-populate the form to show in your app. The way you have to write the Modelform is in the documentation.

Also you can save the new data to that obj. The following code is the same function but checks if the request is a GET or a POST.

```python
def view_function(request, foo):
   obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=foo) # Django shortcut
   if request.method == 'GET':
       # The request uses the GET method, the form is pre-populate with the data of the Model if exists else send an Error 404
       form = NameForm(instance=obj)
       return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'form': form})

   elif request.method == 'POST':
       # The request uses POST, we will get the new data and if it is correct then we will save to the DB else we will show the same page as GET but this time will show the errors.
       form = NameForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return render(request, 'changesSaved.html', {})
       else: # This render will display the errors
           return render(request, 'myTemplate.html', {'form': form})
```

Django shortcuts functions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/

Comment: Hey, thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @manis remember to mark the question as solved. Have a good day ;)